# How to write an aggregation query for mongodb using node

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I would like to write a query to fetch the data from mongodb, I have three collections --books, teachers, students.Book collection have bookName and_id, teachers collection have --_id, teacherName and teacherId, student collection have _id, studentName, teacherId…. I have studentName as S1 and teacherName as T1 with me, how can I fetch the student record with the name S1 which also have the teacherId as the name T1 (from the teacher collection) from the student collection... `eg. select _id from student where studentName =S1 and teacherId=(select techerID from techer where teacherName = T1)… how can I write this query in node using agregation`

```
books.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      'name': 'book1'     }
  }, {

    '$lookup': {

{    from :students,
    '$match': {

      'name': 'Annie'     }
  },
      'from': 'teachers', // collection name of the teachers
      'localField': 'teacherId',
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'teachers'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'teachers': {
        '$elemMatch': {
          'teacherName': 'Jones'
        }
      }
    }
  }
])`
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I've understood you want to fetch the student records using student name and teacher name.

assuming that each student has only a single teacherId.

```
`students.aggregate([
  {
    '$match': {
      'name': 'Anne' // collection name of the students
    }
  }, {
    '$lookup': {
      'from': 'teachers', // collection name of the teachers
      'localField': 'teacherId',
      'foreignField': '_id', 
      'as': 'teachers'
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'teachers': {
        '$elemMatch': {
          'teacherName': 'Jones'
        }
      }
    }
  }
])`
```

Comment: I would also like to fetch data from books collection with name as name, I have used books.agregate and match for doing that, so how can I make the above code like

Comment: is it possible to use two match within the same lokkup..like match annie as well john

Comment: @ Jai ..could yu please help me out, as per yur code I have made some changes in my code